# Getting "bus error" when copying to struct in shared memory

Tags: c, struct

I have this piece of code in my "main" function.

```
...
int data_size1 = sizeof(dados);

int fdDados = shm_open("/dados", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
if (fdDados<0){
    perror("shm_open failed");
    exit(1);
}

dados* shared_data_dados=(dados*) mmap(NULL, data_size1, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fdDados, 0); 
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
char auxMsg[91];
sprintf(auxMsg, "Pid=%d, time=%s", getpid(), asctime(timeinfo));
printf(auxMsg);
strcpy((shared_data_dados->msg), auxMsg);
...
```

and it include the following .h:

```
typedef struct {
    char msg[101];
} dados;
```

The problem is, when I do the strcpy to the struct, it gives me a bus error. I've tried changing the struct to a char*, and placing a char* in the origin part of strcpy but I am still getting the same error.
The printf prints the correct "message" so that shouldn't be the problem...

Any help is apreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just because printf works, it doesn't mean you haven't run off the end of the buffer - print strlen(auxMsg) as well.  Try changing the filename for shmopen to something like "./dados".  shmopen creates a file descriptor - if you do not have access to /, it may not work

Comment: I have tried both of the suggestions and none of them worked. The printf of strlen prints "40", as expcted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to call [`ftruncate(fdDados, SIZE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) to define the size (`SIZE`) of the shared memory object, as described in the [`man 3 shm_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) man page.

   By default, shared memory objects are zero bytes in size. Because your mapping is not backed by the shared memory object, all accesses to the mapping lead to a `SIGBUS` signal being generated.

   It is exactly the same situation as when you memory-map a file, and then try to access the mapping past the end of the file.
2. In the [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) call, the second parameter, the length of the mapping, should be a multiple of page size.

   You can obtain the page size by calling `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`. Do not rely on magic constants or preprocessor macros.
3. Because of (1) and (2) above, it is best to calculate `SIZE` by rounding the amount of shared memory you need to the next multiple of page size. For example:

   ```
   static size_t full_pages(const size_t size)
   {
       size_t page = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
       if (size < page)
           return page;
       else
       if (size % page)
           return size + page - (size % page);
       else
           return size;
   }
   ```

   and in your code,

   ```
   int     shared_fd, len;
   size_t  shared_size;
   dados  *shared_dados;

   shared_size = full_pages(sizeof *shared_dados);
   shared_fd = shm_open("/dados", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
   if (shared_fd == -1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create shared object '/dados': %s.\n", strerror(errno));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (ftruncate(shared_fd, (off_t)shared_size) == -1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Cannot resize shared object '/dados': %s.\n", strerror(errno));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   shared_dados = mmap(NULL, shared_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_SHARED, shared_fd, 0);
   if (shared_dados == MAP_FAILED) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Cannot map shared object '/dados': %s.\n", strerror(errno));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (close(shared_fd) == -1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error closing shared object '/dados': %s.\n", strerror(errno));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   } else
       shared_fd = -1;

   /* TODO: LOCKING! */

   memset(shared_dados->msg, '\0', sizeof shared_dados->msg);
   len = snprintf(shared_dados->msg, sizeof shared_dados->msg, "pid=%ld", (long)getpid());
   if (len < 0 || len >= (int)sizeof shared_dados->msg) {
       /* The string we tried to print was too long to
          fit into the shared_dados->msg field. Oops. */
   }
   ```

   Note that I assume the `msg` member in the `dados` structure is an array of char. If it is a pointer to char, it will not work. (It will point to some random location. Even if you set it to point to within the shared memory object *in this process*, it will point to a wrong address in other processes, because the mapping will essentially be at a random address.)

   Also note the `TODO: LOCKING!` comment. To ensure other processes will only see a complete message, you should use e.g. a mutex around accesses to the `msg` member.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly the problem, ftruncate was missing.